# Bad output format in .txt file

Tags: python, format

i'm trying to print to lexic.txt something like this:

```
Palabra Tag Apariciones
mentales Adj 21
Joaquín_Sánchez_Garrido NP 1
tardíamente Adv 2
repito  V 1
filipinos   Adj 8
```

But the output I get is the following:

```
Palabra Tag Apariciones
mentales Adj 
21
Joaquín_Sánchez_Garrido NP 
1
tardíamente Adv 
2
repito  V 
1
filipinos   Adj 
8
```

And here is the Python code:

```
file=open('corpus.txt','r')
data=file.readlines()
file.close()

diccionario = {}

for linea in data:
    linea.decode('latin_1').encode('UTF-8') # para los acentos
    palabra_tag = linea.split('\n')
    cadena = str(palabra_tag[0])
    if(diccionario.has_key(cadena)):
        aux = diccionario.get(cadena)
        aux += 1
        diccionario.update({cadena:aux})
    else:
        diccionario.update({cadena:1})

outfile = open('lexic.txt', 'w')
outfile.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n')

for key, value in diccionario.iteritems() :
    s = str(value)
    outfile.write(key +" "+s+'\n')
outfile.close()
```

example input file:

```
Al  Prep
menos   Adv
cinco   Det
reclusos    Adj
murieron    V
en  Prep
las Det
últimas Adj
24  Num
horas   NC
en  Prep
las Det
cárceles    NC
de  Prep
Valencia    NP
y   Conj
Barcelona   NP
en  Prep
incidentes  NC
en  Prep
los Det
que Pron
su  Det
```

Basically corpus.txt is a training set with word + tag, so the program reads all the input file and writes an output file with the word + tag and the number of ocurrences in the file.

Can someone help me get the desired result? I am newbie to Python...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged machine-learning?

Comment: @tourniquet_grab it's ok now?

Comment: maybe `outfile.write(key + '\n' + s + '\n')` ?

Comment: @HerrActress Nope, '\n' is for a new line, I want the opposite, keep the key and the value in the same line

Comment: @gerard Ah sorry, I thought you want the exact opposite

Comment: could you also post some lines from the input file?

Comment: @Gerard Well the thing is from the code I did not find any reason for another newline. I have just executed the code with the sample file you provided and it prints to file as you want it `cinco   Det 1`, `que Pron 1` on the same line, and so on...tested on python 2.7 (not sure if it matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work properly for me; however it could be simplified to

```
# Python 3
from collections import Counter

with open("corpus.txt", encoding="latin_1") as inf:
    wordcount = Counter(line.rstrip() for line in inf)

with open("lexic.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outf:
    outf.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n')
    for word,count in wordcount.items():
        outf.write("{}\t{}\n".format(word, count))
```

or

```
# Python 2
from collections import Counter

with open("corpus.txt") as inf:
    wordcount = Counter(line.decode("latin_1").rstrip() for line in inf)

with open("lexic.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n'.encode("utf-8"))
    for word,count in wordcount.iteritems():
        outf.write("{}\t{}\n".format(word, count).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: In the terminal I get: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function (line 3)

Comment: My bad; I only tested in Python 3.4.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, now I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P4.py", line 9, in <module>
    outf.write("{}\t{}\n".format(word, count).encode("utf-8"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 0):

When constructing the output string using format(), you need to make it a UTF-8 string to hold the special characters in your words. The application of the 'ascii' encoding mentioned in the error message indicates this.
Use this:

`for word,count in wordcount.iteritems():
        outf.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(word, count).encode("utf-8"))`

edit:
sorry, this should have shown up following the nearly perfect solution from Hugh. I am just responding to the error Gerard got. Hugh didn't run into this issue as he's running python 3.x which handles strings as unicode by default.